# infinispan hot rod delay

Tags: caching, infinispan, spring-cache

We are using infinispan hot rod in our application.
Some times the retrieval from cache takes more time .This is not happening consistently .  Most of the time it takes 6m sec but at times it takes very long ( 200 msec ) .

The size of the object retrieved from cache is around 200 bytes.

We tested both in infinispn 5.2.1 and JDG 6.3.2

Did anybody face this issue ?

Thanks

Lives

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you're running Java, and that means that garbage collector can fire any time and that will give you 200 ms if you're very lucky, several seconds if you're not and up to minutes if you have large heap and not well tuned GC settings.

As the retrieval from distributed cache requires RPC to another node and handled RPC there, thread scheduling also plays vital role. And in busy system there's no surprise to have the thread waiting.

From Infinispan perspective, there's nothing the retrieval should wait for. The request gets translated into RPC to remote mode, and there it's handled by the same thread that received the message. The request does not wait for any locks.

In JGroups, there may be some delay involved. The message can get lost on network or discarded on receiver if it cannot handle the load, and then it's resent. Also, the UFC protocol makes sure that the receiver speed can match to sender's.

Anything built on top of non-realtime Java works with best effort, and sometimes sh!t happens. 200 ms is still a good response time.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. We are not facing the issue with JDG 6.3.2 for past few days. Will monitor for some more time